# mysql in batch mode

Tags: mysql, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I was trying a large batch of insert statements recently. It took a long time and found that mysql supports batch mode, so I did a test with batch mode.

#### Test1:

```
    @Test
    public void testSingleService() {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                iLostProductService.insertProduct(new Product("testSingleService" + i));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

mybatis.xml

```
    <sql id = "baseSql">
        product_name
    </sql>

    <insert id="insertProduct" parameterType="com.team.lof.model.Product">
        insert into product (<include refid="baseSql"></include>) values (#{name})
    </insert>
```

**It takes a very long time, i give up this way.**

#### Test2:

```
    @Test
    public void testBatchService() {
        List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<Product>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            productList.add(new Product("2227testBatchService" + i));
        }
        try {
            iLostProductService.insertProductList(productList);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

mybatis.xml

```
    <insert id="insertProductList">
        insert into product (<include refid="baseSql"></include>) values 
        <foreach collection="productList" item="product" separator=",">
            (#{product.name})
        </foreach>
    </insert>
```

**It takes 1s 329ms, pretty fast.**

#### Test3:

**Turn on batch mode, spring.datasource.url** needs to configure **rewriteBatchedStatements=true**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/lof?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&allowMultiQueries=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=GMT&rewriteBatchedStatements=true
```

```
    @Test
    public void testBatchExcutorService() {
        SqlSession sqlSession = null;
        try {
            sqlSession = sqlSessionFactory.openSession(ExecutorType.BATCH);
            ProductDao batchProductDao = sqlSession.getMapper(ProductDao.class);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                batchProductDao.insertProduct(new Product("2047testBatchExcutorService" + i));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            sqlSession.commit();
            sqlSession.close();
        }
    }
```

mybatis.xml

```
    <insert id="insertProduct" parameterType="com.team.lof.model.Product">
        insert into product (<include refid="baseSql"></include>) values (#{name})
    </insert>
```

**It takes 1s 119ms, fastest.**

I captured and analyzed the packets separately. The size of each packet in test 1 is 151 bytes, and the size of each packet in test 2 and test 3 is 1466 bytes. Test 2 sent a total of 634 packets with a total size of 575925 bytes. 3 A total of 452 packets were sent with a total size of 392,882 bytes. I checked the packet data of test 2 and test 3 with a size of 1466 bytes, and found that the packet of test 3 was compressed. Is this the reason for the fast batch mode?

Comment: Do you really want to know if sending 392Kb to the server, in stead of 576Kb is making the process much quicker?

Comment: Yes, because I can’t find other differences

Comment: I found another difference, PreparedStatement will not be performed in batch mode

Comment: What about the number of [transactions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-transaction.html) that are done in your `Test1` compared to `Test3` ?

Comment: Test 2 uses spring's transaction management，like this.                               
 ```    
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public int insertProductList(List<Product> productList) throws Exception {
        int result = productDao.insertProductList(productList);
        return result;
    }
```
Test 3 manually open the transaction and submit.  
I think the two tests are in one transaction.

Comment: [Why does TRANSACTION / COMMIT improve performance so much with PHP/MySQL (InnoDB)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675147/why-does-transaction-commit-improve-performance-so-much-with-php-mysql-innodb)

Comment: The comparison of the problem is: in the case of automatic commit, each time SQL is executed, the transaction will be automatically committed, and when the transaction is manually opened, there is only one transaction

Comment: And there is only one transaction in my test 2 and test 3

Comment: Multi-row insert (=Test2) builds a single `PreparedStatement` with many placeholders `?`. Its performance gets worse when there are many columns and/or items in the list. JDBC batch (=Test3) builds a simple `PreparedStatement` (with one placeholder in you case) and reuse it which gives the driver a chance to optimize the internal process (like `rewriteBatchedStatements` in MySQL). The actual performance depends on various factors, but using batch executor is the recommended way when dealing with a large data set.

Comment: Yes, although I don't know how to optimize it internally in MYSQL, but judging from the amount of data transmitted on the network, the execution time has nothing to do with packet compression.